# Palindromes function does not work

Tags: python, palindrome

This is what I have so far. What should I do to get this to work?

```
def num_pal(nums):
    for x in nums: 
        w=

def pals(x):
    pos=0
    pos1=-1
    for n in x:
        if n[pos]==n[pos1]:
            pos=pos+1
            pos1=pos1-1
            return'true'
        else:
            return'false'
```

Comment: we aren't here to do homework

Comment: here's a favor: stack overflow is for helping people resolve problems with their code. It expects evidence of effort, typically demonstrated by posting the code you have tried so far and explaining what it is or is not doing. In your case, you don't even ask a question. It looks like you just posted a homework assignment and expect the community to just do it for you. We can help if you show what you have tried. If not, then it is not help.

Comment: thats what i have so far

Comment: ok. you may also want to edit this and add the programming language as a tag. Some people subscribe to languages so you might get more help by mentioning it in tags, title, or body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this function:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text[:len(text)//2] == text[:(len(text)-1)//2:-1]
```

Here is example usage for reference:

```
>>> is_palindrome('')
True
>>> is_palindrome('a')
True
>>> is_palindrome('b')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aa')
True
>>> is_palindrome('ab')
False
>>> is_palindrome('ba')
False
>>> is_palindrome('bb')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aaa')
True
>>> is_palindrome('aab')
False
>>> is_palindrome('aba')
True
```